# How to map a network drive inside a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, network-drive

My users are use to map network drives.

I developed a tools, which use a network drive i:.

Problem : I may overlap a user-defined drive.

How can I open a dos batch file which will define a new network drive for its own usage but that will not change the network drives visible by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
pushd \\server\share
```

it will map a drive on the first available letter

the drive will be disconnect when running `popd`

Current directory may be obtained through the environement variabble `%cd%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to find an available drive letter.

```
for %%d in (z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g) do if not exist %%d:\* set drive=%%d
```

Then use %drive%: in place of I: throughout your bat file.
e.g. `net use %drive%: \\server...`

Answer (score 0):

The drive letter system is nowadays quite outdated, you may want to substitue yourself in the path.

```
s/^i:\/\\SomeServer\SomeShare\
```

Cordially

Comment: Not all windows batch commands will work with UNC paths. Pushd will work then, too.